# Django: After saving the Order and deleting the cart, Order looses information of ordered items

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I want the cart items to be saved in each order. But after the cart is deleted, "service_items" becomes empty.

Steps:

1. Add items to the cart
2. Save order
3. Delete cart

I think `service_items = models.ManyToManyField(Cart)` is causing the issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Current Order object after saving:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "customer": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Some",
        "last_name": "User",
        "email": "someuser@gmail.com",
        "phone_number": "+817056781234",
        "member_date": "2023-01-28T14:38:43.196580Z"
    },
    "status": false,
    "total": "15.00",
    "order_date": "2023-01-28T16:05:11.704636Z",
    "delivery_date": "2023-01-31T12:52:16.193078Z",
    "advance_payment": "9.00",
    "payment_method": "cash",
    "due_payment": 6.0,
    "service_items": []
}
```

Expected outcome:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "customer": {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Some",
        "last_name": "User",
        "email": "someuser@gmail.com",
        "phone_number": "+817056781234",
        "member_date": "2023-01-28T14:38:43.196580Z"
    },
    "status": false,
    "total": "15.00",
    "order_date": "2023-01-28T16:05:11.704636Z",
    "delivery_date": "2023-01-31T12:52:16.193078Z",
    "advance_payment": "9.00",
    "payment_method": "cash",
    "due_payment": 6.0,
    "service_items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "service_item": {
                "id": 1,
                "item_name": "Black Shirt",
                "description": "Half and Full Sleeve Black Shirts.",
                "wash_price": "3.00",
                "stain_treatment_price": "1.00",
                "iron_price": "2.00",
                "dry_wash_price": "4.00",
                "category": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "Shirt"
                }
            },
            "is_wash": false,
            "is_stain_treatment": true,
            "is_iron": false,
            "is_dry_wash": true,
            "quantity": 3,
            "unit_price": "5.00",
            "price": "15.00",
            "customer": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

models.py

```
class ServiceItem(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    
    wash_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    stain_treatment_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    iron_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    dry_wash_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)                                                    

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.item_name

class Cart(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_item = models.ForeignKey(ServiceItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    is_wash = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_stain_treatment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_iron = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_dry_wash = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('service_item', 'customer')                                                                   

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer} - {self.service_item}'

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_items = models.ManyToManyField(Cart)
    status = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days = 1))
    advance_payment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=70, db_index=True, default="cash")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer} - {self.order_date}'
```

serializers.py

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    service_item = ServiceItemSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = '__all__'


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    due_payment = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='calculate_balance')
    service_items = CartSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'customer', 'status', 'total', 'order_date', 'delivery_date',
                    'advance_payment', 'payment_method', 'due_payment', 'service_items']                         
        depth = 1

    def calculate_balance(self, product:Order):
        if product.advance_payment > 0:
            return Decimal(product.total - product.advance_payment)
        else:
            return Decimal(product.total)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def cart(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = Cart.objects.all()
        serialized_items = CartSerializer(items, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_items.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        customer_phone = request.data.get("customer_phone")
        customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, phone_number=customer_phone)                                         # Customer Info
        
        item_name = request.data['item']
        item = get_object_or_404(ServiceItem, item_name=item_name)
        item_quantity = int(request.data['quantity'])

        wash = request.data['is_wash']
        stain_treatment = request.data['is_stain_treatment']
        iron = request.data['is_iron']
        dry_wash = request.data['is_dry_wash']

        item_price = Decimal(0)
        if wash:
            item_price += item.wash_price
        if stain_treatment:
            item_price += item.stain_treatment_price
        if iron:
            item_price += item.iron_price
        if dry_wash:
            item_price += item.dry_wash_price

        cart_item = Cart(customer_id=customer.id, service_item=item, is_wash=wash, 
                        is_stain_treatment=stain_treatment, is_iron=iron, is_dry_wash=dry_wash,
                        quantity=item_quantity, unit_price=item_price, price=Decimal(item_price*item_quantity))
        try:
            cart_item.save()
        except:
            return Response({'message': 'The item may have already been added to the cart'}, 
                            status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        return Response({'message': '{} {} has been added succesfully'.format(item_quantity,item_name)},
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
# @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@throttle_classes([UserRateThrottle])
def orders(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        orders = Order.objects.all()
        serialized_orders = OrderSerializer(orders, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_orders.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, phone_number=customer_phone)
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(customer=customer)
        if cart:
            total = cart.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
            # discount = ???
            # staff = ??
            delivery_date = request.data.get("delivery_date")
            advance_payment = Decimal(request.data.get("advance_payment"))
            payment_method = request.data.get("payment_method")
            
            order = Order.objects.create(customer=customer, total=total, delivery_date=delivery_date, 
                                            advance_payment=advance_payment, payment_method=payment_method)              
                
            order.service_items.set(cart)
            order.save()
            
            
            cart.delete()
            return Response({'message': 'Order successfully placed'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'Cart is Empty'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Is there any other way to implement what I am expecting?

Comment: I am not able to understand the Q properly. Correct me when I'm wrong. You want first to add items to the cart. And after this you are Save the order which means buying the order??? and if the order is done successfully then you want to delete the cart right??

Comment: @NikhilKotiya Yes, you are correct.